# Vue | Module has no default export

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I'm facing an error with vue3, ts, vue cli where it says
`Module '"c:/Users/USER/Documents/top-secret-project/src/components/Features/Features.vue"' has no default export.`
when importing a component from a file
I have no idea why did this specific component decide to now work.

here's Features.vue

```html
<script lang="ts">
import Feature from "./Feature.vue";
</script>

<template>
  <Feature />
</template>
```

Comment: Please share the content of `Features.vue`?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim, it's just a div with script setup and inside it is an import of a component

Comment: so where is said setup in your code?

Comment: Oh, well I didn't notice it ;-;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With script setup syntax there's no need to add `export default` in your script, just add the `setup` attribute to your script:

```html
<script lang="ts" setup>
import Feature from "./Feature.vue";
</script>

<template>
  <Feature />
</template>
```

You should disable vetur extension and use Volar instead of it

Comment: I'm using Vue 3 with vite and I'm thinking something is wrong with Vetur, because my code has setup as you said and it keep saying no export default in module

Comment: @Shad, you should disable vetur extension and use Volar instead of it

Answer (score 27):

A @Boussadjra mentioned this could happen in Visual Studio Code if Vetur extension is installed there.
Insetted of `Vetur` if we install `Volar` extension in Visual Studio Code this problem gets solved.

Comment: This issue is addressed in the vue 3 documentation, https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html#volar-takeover-mode.

Comment: Adding to this answer, they have now marked Volar as deprecated and recommend to use Vue - Official extension instead (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Vue.volar)

Answer (score 2):

You must add export default in your component's script by example:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "HelpView",
};
</script>
```